# Laravel query relationship where clause

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

**I need filter by departamento**, like `where('departamento_id', '=', 1)`.

Tables:

```
membro_bancas
id
departamento_id
user_id


trabalhos
id
titulo
orientador_id (references id of membro_bancas)
coorientador_id (references id of membro_bancas)
```

I have this code:

```
$trabalho = Trabalho::with('membrobanca.departamento')
    ->with('coorientador')
    ->with('academico')
    ->get();
```

And returns this:

[image]

Comment: try doing 
$trabalho = Trabalho::with('membrobanca.departamento')
    ->with('coorientador')
    ->with('academico')
    ->where('membrobanca.departamento.departamento_id', '=' , 1)
    ->get();

Comment: btw, which ID do you want to filter? is it on the 'membrobanca' or in 'departamento' ?

Comment: What is the difference? Because I need retrieve all Trabalhos with yours academicos and membrobancas and coorientador and filtering by departamento of membrobanca

Comment: If that's the case then you could just write all the filtering. So, Example.
->where('coorientador.departamento_id', '=', 1)
->where('membrobancas.departamento_id', '=', 1)

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!

I needed add `orWhereHas` for `coorientador` too. The result is this:

```
Trabalho::whereHas('membrobanca', function($q) use ($departamento_id) {
    $q->where('departamento_id', '=', $departamento_id);
})
->orWhereHas('coorientador', function($q) use ($departamento_id) {
    $q->where('departamento_id', '=', $departamento_id);
})
->with('academico')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this eloquent filter using **whereas**

```
$trabalho = Trabalho::whereHas('membrobanca',function($query) use ($id){
     $query->where('departamento_id', '=', $id)
})
->with('coorientador')
->with('academico')
->get();
```

example of filter using **with**

```
$trabalho = Trabalho::with(['membrobanca',function($query) use ($id){
     $query->where('departamento_id', '=', $id)
}])
->with('coorientador')
->with('academico')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Works for membrobanca and how do it for coorientador? I tried including `whereHas` for coorientador but does not worked...

Comment: what you need to filter for coorientador ?